# Enable or disable Option Controls on Form_Load() based on the record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a couple un-linked (they are not part of an option group) option controls on it.  When one is clicked, the other (and text boxes associated to it) are disabled.  This all works great using the code below, but I can't get it to work out correctly on ''Form_Load()''.

Here is the code I'm using for the `AfterUpdate()` routines:

```
Private Sub optInclusive_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.optInclusive Then
        Me.optMonthly.Enabled = False
        Me.txtMonthlyRate.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.optMonthly.Enabled = True
        Me.txtMonthlyRate.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub optMonthly_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.optMonthly Then
        Me.optInclusive.Enabled = False
        Me.txtInclusiveRate.Enabled = False
        Me.txtDateFrom.Enabled = False
        Me.txtDateTo.Enabled = False
        Me.txtTimeFrameRate.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.optInclusive.Enabled = True
        Me.txtInclusiveRate.Enabled = True
        Me.txtDateFrom.Enabled = True
        Me.txtDateTo.Enabled = True
        Me.txtTimeFrameRate.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried just putting this code in `Form_Load()`, but when the form loads, it disables ALL the controls, no matter the record loaded.

*Here is what happens when the form is loaded with a specific form:*

[image: View for Form_Load]

*Here is what SHOULD happen on form load:*

[image: View from New record, etc.]

Comment: I guess you have no or the wrong *Default Value* set for `Me.optMonthly` and `Me.optInclusive`.

Comment: You want on default load set `optMonthly =True?` Can you not code it like that in `Form_Load`?

Comment: By default they are shown on ``Form_Load()``

Comment: Actually, I should have done this before I responded originally - but I went and checked and yes, by default they were set to No.  I removed the default value from the table and I get an invalid use of Null error.  I could probably suppress that error, but I'd rather do it "correctly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Form_Current`, not `Form_Load`

On `Form_Load`, the current record is not yet loaded. `Current` triggers every time a new record is loaded, so also re-initializes the state when switching records. I guess that's what you want.

Comment: By George you got it!  Thank ya, sir!